# Converting Boolean to Integer SQl Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert a boolean to an integer.  Here is the coding I have so far:

```
CONVERT(int, column_name) AS ALIAS
```

The query runs without an error.  However, it is not producing the results I want.

What do I need to do?

Comment: I should note that it does convert the values to integers.  However, it only returns 0s.  Why is this happening?

Comment: Why do you need a boolean to be an integer? they're already effectually only 1 or 0. Why not just check for true or false?

Comment: Maybe all the records have false in that field.  What is the rdbms?  That's relevant.

Comment: you mean you converting BIT to integer? Can u show sample data from "column_name" ?

Comment: I need to convert it to an int because I want to aggregate it.  I'm using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are doing should be enough to convert BIT values to int as shown below.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(Value BIT)

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
(1),(0),(1),(0),(1),(0),(1)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT  Value
       ,CAST(Value AS INT)  AS Casted
       ,CONVERT(int, Value) AS Converted
FROM @TABLE
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═══════╦════════╦═══════════╗
║ Value ║ Casted ║ Converted ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║     1 ║      1 ║         1 ║
║     0 ║      0 ║         0 ║
║     1 ║      1 ║         1 ║
║     0 ║      0 ║         0 ║
║     1 ║      1 ║         1 ║
║     0 ║      0 ║         0 ║
║     1 ║      1 ║         1 ║
╚═══════╩════════╩═══════════╝
```